# Best way to construct a semantic HTML table?

Tags: html, html5

I have to do a table like this one:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|         th 1          | th 2  | th 3  | th 4  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 1  | td 2  | td 3  |
|       |       | th 7  +-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 4  | td 5  | td 6  |
|       | th 6  +-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 7  | td 8  | td 9  |
|       |       | th 8  +-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 10 | td 11 | td 12 |
| th 5  +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 13 | td 14 | td 15 |
|       |       | th 10 +-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 16 | td 17 | td 18 |
|       | th 9  +-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 19 | td 20 | td 21 |
|       |       | th 11 +-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       | td 22 | td 23 | td 24 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The way I'm doing it right now is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">th 1</th>
            <th>th 2</th>
            <th>th 3</th>
            <th>th 4</th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="8">th 5</th>
             <th rowspan="4">th 6</th>
             <th rowspan="2">th 7</th>
             <td>td 1</td>
             <td>td 2</td>
             <td>td 3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>td 4</td>
             <td>td 5</td>
             <td>td 6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="2">th 8</th>
             <td>td 7</td>
             <td>td 8</td>
             <td>td 9</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>td 10</td>
             <td>td 11</td>
             <td>td 12</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="4">th 9</th>
             <th rowspan="2">th 10</th>
             <td>td 13</td>
             <td>td 14</td>
             <td>td 15</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>td 16</td>
             <td>td 17</td>
             <td>td 18</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th rowspan="2">th 11</th>
             <td>td 19</td>
             <td>td 20</td>
             <td>td 21</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>22</td>
             <td>23</td>
             <td>24</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

What I want to know is if there is another, cleaner way to construct the same structure, like having the `td` in `tr` different than the same in which the `th` are constructed to have them separated.

I created a jsfiddle if anyone knows a better way to do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/mkhuete/ehX7X/1/

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: The structure looks OK. Nothing has been said about semantics (i.e., meanings) involved. The question “if there is another way, more clean to construct these same structure, like having the td in tr differents than the same in which the th are constructed to have them separated” just does not parse, still less make sense.

Comment: Because of the clean, it looks clean I like the table "colgroup" tag and maybe this link will help a little too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006089/setting-rowspan-on-colgroup

Answer (score 12):

I can't fault your tags at all. The only problem is that due to your table being quite complex, assistive technology may not be able to figure out the structure of your table.

I was going to recommend using `scope` but according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63.html) there are some inconsistency issues.

> The row and col values of the scope attribute are currently supported
>   to a large extent by most current versions of JAWS. However, **there are
>   still some problems and WindowEyes support for scope is inconsistent**.
>   The same is true for Japanese versions of these screen readers.
>   Versions of JAWS prior to version 5 and older versions of Window-Eyes
>   have inconsistent support for scope.

Using `scope` would look like this, with `scope="col"` in all `<th>` elements in the first row and `scope="row"` for all other `<th>` elements.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" scope="col">th 1</th>
            <th scope="col">th 2</th>
            <th scope="col">th 3</th>
            <th scope="col">th 4</th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="8" scope="row">th 5</th>
            <th rowspan="4" scope="row">th 6</th>
            <th rowspan="2" scope="row">th 7</th>
            <td>td 1</td>
            <td>td 2</td>
            <td>td 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td 4</td>
            <td>td 5</td>
            <td>td 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" scope="row">th 8</th>
            <td>td 7</td>
            <td>td 8</td>
            <td>td 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td 10</td>
            <td>td 11</td>
            <td>td 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4" scope="row">th 9</th>
            <th rowspan="2" scope="row">th 10</th>
            <td>td 13</td>
            <td>td 14</td>
            <td>td 15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td 16</td>
            <td>td 17</td>
            <td>td 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" scope="row">th 11</th>
            <td>td 19</td>
            <td>td 20</td>
            <td>td 21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>td 22</td>
            <td>td 23</td>
            <td>td 24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle for scope method](http://jsfiddle.net/CY66k/1/.)

This is W3C's recommendation:

> At the current time, **those who want to ensure consistent support
>   across Assistive Technologies for tables** where the headers are not in
>   the first row/column may want to use the technique for complex tables
>   **H43: [Using id and headers attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43.html)** to associate data cells with
>   header cells in data tables. For simple tables that have headers in
>   the first column or row we recommend the use of the th and td
>   elements.

Let me just start off by saying this is a complete pain in order to be completely accessibly and scope will probably be fine in most cases. Here is the table using the `id`/`header` method (*shudder*):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" id="th1">th 1</th>
            <th id="th2">th 2</th>
            <th id="th3">th 3</th>
            <th id="th4">th 4</th>
        </tr>            
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="8" id="th5" headers="th1">th 5</th>
            <th rowspan="4" id="th6" headers="th1 th5">th 6</th>
            <th rowspan="2" id="th7" headers="th1 th5 th6">th 7</th>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th6 th7">td 1</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th6 th7">td 2</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th6 th7">td 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th6 th7">td 4</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th6 th7">td 5</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th6 th7">td 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" id="th8" headers="th1 th5 th6">th 8</th>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th6 th8">td 7</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th6 th8">td 8</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th6 th8">td 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th6 th8">td 10</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th6 th8">td 11</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th6 th8">td 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4" id="th9" headers="th1 th5">th 9</th>
            <th rowspan="2" id="th10" headers="th1 th5 th9">th 10</th>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th9 th10">td 13</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th9 th10">td 14</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th9 th10">td 15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th9 th10">td 16</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th9 th10">td 17</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th9 th10">td 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" id="th11" headers="th1 th5 th9">th 11</th>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th9 th11">td 19</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th9 th11">td 20</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th9 th11">td 21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="th2 th5 th9 th11">td 22</td>
            <td headers="th3 th5 th9 th11">td 23</td>
            <td headers="th4 th5 th9 th11">td 24</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle for id/headers](http://jsfiddle.net/ehX7X/9/)

What is comes down to in the end in my opinion is an accessible solution that is also maintainable in the back end. Realistically JAWS and WindowEyes will eventually fix up their bugs and using `scope` will be fine even for tables as complex as this. Unless you expect many users to use assistive technologies and require strict adherence to WCAG, go with `scope`. Markup needs to be beautiful too :)

There is also the [`<colgroup>`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/colgroup) element which is relevant but support for it isn't great currently.

Comment: Thanks! it's an interesting approach, thanks for helping me

Answer (score -2):

Plan it out on paper with percentages, and then take it row by row in an editor, inserting the content as you go. Otherwise you can't do it at all. And the more cells and custom rowspan/colspan you use with coding non-CSS table design, the time taken to code it all increases exponentially.

Comment: The author has already sketched the layout, and the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes are already correct. Furthermore, the question is about semantics, not layout.